# setDiscoverTargets is not allowed for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am trying to develop a chrome extension and in this extension, I need the target related events (targetCreated/targetInfoChanged/targetDestroyed).

To achieve that goal I am using [setDiscoverTargets](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-setDiscoverTargets) method from the devtools protocol by means of [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/) API. Here is the pseudocode that I am using:

```
   // attach the debugger 
    
        chrome.debugger.attach(debuggeeId, version, onAttach);
    
    // when attach is successful send setAuthAttach to make setDiscoverTargets command work
        const onAttach = (debuggeeId) => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`onAttach: ${JSON.stringify(debuggeeId)}`);
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: myTabId }, "Target.setAutoAttach", { autoAttach: false, waitForDebuggerOnStart: false, flatten: true }, setAutoAttachHandler);
        }

// when auto attach handler is successful send setDiscoverTargets method      
// to enable targetCreated/targetInfoChanged/targetDestroyed events

        const setAutoAttachHandler = (result) => {
           if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
               console.log("error in setAutoAttachHandler:" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
               return;
           }
           console.log(`setAutoAttachHandler result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: myTabId }, 'Target.setDiscoverTargets', { discover: true }, setDiscoverTargetsHandler);
        }

    // see the result of command 
        const setDiscoverTargetsHandler = (result) => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log("error in setDiscoverTargetsHandler:" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`setDiscoverTargets result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        }
```

As per execute the code above I am always getting `not allowed` error

> error in setDiscoverTargetsHandler:{"code":-32000,"message":"Not
> allowed"}

And the events related to the target are not fired. Is there anything else I should do to get those events?

thank you.

Comment: That's because by default auto-attach mode is enabled so you shouldn't need setDiscoverTargets. If you really think you need it then disable auto-attach mode first by using Target.setAutoAttach.

Comment: I also tried it, but no luck: I am getting the same `not allowed` response from setDiscoverTargets method, @wOxxOm. What can be the other reason?

Comment: Without seeing the code I have to assume it was incorrect.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, I edit the question around the details of how I used `setAutoAttach` as you suggested. Do think that it is incorrect?

Comment: The code looks fine but I haven't used these commands myself so I can't really help further. Try changing parameters e.g. waitForDebuggerOnStart: `true`

Comment: @wOxxOm, I tried waitForDebuggerOnStart: `true` option and result is the same. Again, I am getting `not allowed` result. 
I am also stuck here and there is no good documentation on what happens why. But, anyway thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Methods under `Target` and `Browser` domain(except for Browser.getVersion) are not allowed when sending command from `chrome.debugger` api. But if you want to observe for tabs to which debugger is attached or tabs in which developer tools is opened then you can poll `chrome.debugger.getTargets` at regular intervals. You will get response, something like this :-

```json
[{
    "attached": true,
    "faviconUrl": "https://www.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico",
    "id": "DEA9ED6A4A3DFB9A6FC315AF7110465B",
    "tabId": 88,
    "title": "Wikipedia",
    "type": "page",
    "url": "https://www.wikipedia.org/,
}, {
    "attached": false,
    "faviconUrl": "https://github.githubassets.com/favicons/favicon.svg",
    "id": "3314432045C3EC141D4C7D7023606122",
    "tabId": 87,
    "title": "GitHub",
    "type": "page",
    "url": "https://github.com/"
}]
```